# Как запретить действия на потомка ,сделанное с помощью toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть анимация,при нажатии div увеличивается ,при еще одном нажатии уменьшается.

```
$("#topbar").toggle(function () {

    $("#topbar").animate({
        width: 300
    }, 400);

    $("#topbar").animate({
        height: 400
    }, 400);

}, function () {

    $(this).animate({
        height: 40
    }, 400);
    $(this).animate({
        width: 40
    }, 400);


});
```

дело в том,что внутри этого блока еще один,в котором форма,при клике да объект формы ,срабатывает анимация и #topbar закрывается
preventDefault и  stopPropagation не пашут,подскажите,что делать
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял:

```
// js
$("#btn_send").click(function() {
    $("#btn_send").parent().submit();
    // $("#btn_send").parent() - ваша форма, можете дать ей id и получить доступ явно.
});
```

Также может помочь [отмена событий](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Все равно убирается.Я вернул как было,вот http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/zac3sso9/

Comment: Поправил, вас почти не понять без кода)

Comment: А как сделать,что бы можно было поля заполнять,сейчас при заполнении,уезжает блок

Comment: В конце моего поста ссылка. Сделайте как там.
Создайте функцию и hamdle на нее, начначте свою функцию либо явно только тем элементам которым она нужна, либо назначте всему диву отменив (unbind) для елементов которые не должны работать с вашей функцией.

Comment: $('#topbar_info').unbind('toggle'); Чет не работает. Так по факту на него события то и нет,Нужно как то запрещать действия предку от потомка. Или я где то ошибся в коде?

Comment: Перечитайте пожайлуста всю статью которая в моей ссылке, unbind работает только с теме событиями которые были заданы как bind, и она принимает минимум 2 параметра.
Unbind нужно делать наверное при клики/фокусировки в любом инпуте, а при потери фокуса опять биндить...

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26122/discussion-between-makarenko-i-v-and-zkolya).

Comment: Не подскажете,в чем косяк,вроде все по туториалу делал http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/zac3sso9/1/

Comment: Я не увидел что бы вы внесли туда изменения.
Как вариант откажитесь от togglet, сделайте событие click.
А форму сделайте скрытой, и не внутри тега див, применив абсолютное позиционирование. Делайте ей show, hide.

Comment: Тут изменения $("#topbar").bind('toggle', function () {

Comment: Но вы не где не делаете unbind.
Перечитайте материал в ссылке, и по тестируйте на более простом примере.

Comment: для того что бы сделать unbindнужно добиться того,что бы  просто bind работал

Comment: Убедитесь что bind умеет создавать ивент для togglet, может быть придется использовать click и самому писать функционал togglet.

Comment: Спасибо.Буду пробовать)